# Commits not shown in GitHub Desktop, show up on github.com

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I'm using GitHub Desktop.

It's not showing 2 commits that show up correctly on github.com.

I deleted the repository and cloned it again, but the problem persists.

What could be the cause of this? What can I do to try to fix it?

Comment: Is invisible commits first/last in chain or at the middle?

Comment: Does command line git see the commits locally? If the repository is public, can you provide links for the commits in question?

Comment: Nope, the command line doesn't list them. Only on github.com. Unfortunately the repo is private :-/